# Okhttp3 синглтон не рабоатет

Tags: android, android-studio, okhttp

Студия не дает ответ с сервера запиать в переменную. Почему? Что сделал не так? объявить ее как final пробовал - проблемы не решает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    package ru.tehnomaks.carpark.Singletons;

import java.io.IOException;

import eu.amirs.JSON;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MyRequest {

private static MyRequest INSTANCE = null;

private static final String SERVER_URL = "ссылка";

//==============================================================================================

// конструктор
private MyRequest() {
}

// первичный доступ/создание одиночки
public static MyRequest getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new MyRequest();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

// метод возвращает json-объект после запроса на сервер
public static JSON request(String sRequest) {
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");                        // тип и коодировка JSON-объекта передаваемого в запросе на сервер

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();                                                   // клиент
    RequestBody body;                                                                           // тело запроса
    Request request;                                                                            // запрос на сервер
    Response response;                                                                          // ответ от сервера
    JSON jsonResponse = null;                                                                   // сюда заношу ответ от сервера, конвертнув его в JSON

    body = RequestBody.create(JSON, sRequest);                                                  // тело запроса
    request = new Request.Builder()                                                             // запрос
            .url(SERVER_URL)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            jsonResponse = new JSON(response.body().string());                                      // конвертнул ответ в JSON-объект

        }
    });

    client.connectionPool().evictAll();                                                         

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Comment: Вы выполняете асинхронный запрос и не можете вернуть его результат `return`'ом метода `request(...)` ни в коем случае. Либо передавайте коллбэк параметром, а реализуйте его в месте вызова; либо переделывайте под синхронный запрос, но метод нужно будет вызывать в фоновом потоке.

Comment: Во вложенных классах (в Вашем случае анонимная реализация `Callback`) нельзя изменять внешние переменные, если они не являются полями другого класса. Можно только брать из них значения

Comment: `// метод возвращает json-объект после запроса на сервер` -- ошибка, метод будет возвращать всегда `null`. Метод стоит переименовать в `startRequest()`, тогда становится обычно яснее, что раз он что-то просто стартует, не может возвращать результат того, что только запустилось и непонятно когда отработает.

Comment: @woesss, с реализацией в месте вызова понял. А вот про синхронный запрос в фоновом потоке не очень. Мне надо в этом же классе просто добавить реализацию фонового потока и уже в нем присваивать переменную?

Comment: Не так. Вместо асинхронного `enqeue(...)` использовать синхронный `execute()`, но сам метод  `request(...)` можно будет вызывать только в фоновом потоке (поскольку Андроид запрещает ходить в сеть в главном). При синхронном запросе метод сможет вернуть результат по завершении. Если Вы внутри метода сделаете фоновый поток - это опять будет асинхронный запрос, что означает что сначала закончится метод и вернёт `null`, а потом когда-нибудь выполнится запрос.